# How can I create an internal class with CodeDom using CodeTypeDeclaration?

Tags: c#, roslyn, codedom

How can I create an internal class with CodeDom using CodeTypeDeclaration?

Trying [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration.typeattributes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_CodeDom_CodeTypeDeclaration_TypeAttributes) example makes it private.

LE: Found the answer, so I'll post it here if someone needs it.

```
myType.TypeAttributes = (myType.TypeAttributes & ~TypeAttributes.VisibilityMask) | TypeAttributes.NestedAssembly;
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Comment: Sorry for not adding an example. Added the answer in case someone needs it, I guess this could take place of an example.

Comment: @Kosmo Please add the answer as an answer, not by adding it to the question. You can mark it as the accepted answer in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, so I'll post it here if someone needs it.

```
myType.TypeAttributes = (myType.TypeAttributes & ~TypeAttributes.VisibilityMask) | TypeAttributes.NestedAssembly;
```